# DVD rental SQL ###### QUERY

Tags: sql, database

Trying to find how many active or inactive rentals there are for a specific store. 1 = active, 0 = inactive. the answer I get doubles the amount of customers and is not right. Can anyone help

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM customer, store
WHERE active = 0
AND store_id = 2
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Try supplying a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which means include sample data. Also tag the relevant DBMS.

That being said, it looks like you're not supplying a join condition combining the tables _customer_ and _store_. This gives you the cartesian product of your tables, which might be the cause of any duplicates.

Comment: You probably want to `GROUP BY` too.

Comment: Please EDIT your post.  Clarify which tables have what columns.  I can GUESS, but best if you provide the columns now and in future.  If you have one customer associated with multiple stores could skew counts.  Do you want counts per store?  As it is now, you are just getting a single count due to no GROUP BY clause.  We can help, but again, please EDIT your post and provide additional info.

Answer (score 1):

The join is incorrect. There are no join  criteria specified so the result is all possible combinations of customers and stores, filtered by `where` clause.

Correct way to join is:

```
...
from customer inner join store on store.store_id = customer.store_id
...
```

(assuming `customer` table has the `store_id` field).

And you probably want to group by store using the `group by` clause.